# Issues with functions in Octave programming language

Tags: function, octave

I have defined some functions in Octave. Everytime I run them it suggests a error for "undefined" in line or line 4 or something arbitrary like that. From my experience this happens when you copy paste code or something but I have retyepd some of this from scratch to have the same issues. Could anyone care to point out what I am doing wrong.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUsvG.png):

```
Program paused. Press enter to continue.
>> pause;

>> % Complete warmUpExercise.m

Running warmUpExercise ...
>> fprintf('5x5 Identity Matrix: \n');

5x5 Identity Matrix:
>> warmUpExercise()

error: 'warmUpExercise' undefinednear line 1 column 1
>> fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');

Program paused. Press enter to continue.
>> pause;
```

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOVAA.png):

```
function A=warmupexercise()
  %WARMUPEXERCISE
  %to return a 5x5 matrix
  A=[];
  % MY CODE %
  Instructions: Return the 5x5 identity matrix
%              In octave, we return values by defining which variables
%              represent the return values (at the top of the file)
%              and then set them accordingly.
  A=zeros(5);
endfunction
```

And this the simplest function in the assignment so it's unlikely there is error with the primary code.

Answer (score 0):

function names are case sensitive.  note how the actual function name defined in the code block is all lowercase.  Also, from the image you posted it appears the function file is saved as `warmUpExercise (1).m`.  save the file name to match the function (as warmupexercise.m) and then   try calling the function as: `warmupexercise()`  not `warmUpExercise`.